# Flutter update progress in compute method

Tags: flutter, dart, single-threaded

I have to save many images to the device to make videos.
As saving multiple images takes so much time and resources, I use compute to save images.

I want to show the progress in saving images so that users can notice how much time left for video.
But, calling `progressDialog.update(progress: progress)` in compute cause error like this

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: Invalid argument(s): Illegal argument in isolate message : (object is a closure - Function _handleBuildScheduled@587399801:.)
```

**How can I show progress in compute method?**

Comment: basically you cannot pass any closure (function) as a parameter to `compute` method: you can only use `ReceivePort` / `SendPort` stuff

Comment: Is there any examples for ReceivePort/SentPort ?

Comment: there are no samples in the official documentation

Comment: I'm sorry. I cant find message parameter in compute method. it says required parameter is 2 not 3.

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/foundation/compute.html - it says: `Future<R> Function<Q, R>(
ComputeCallback<Q, R> callback,
Q message,
{String? debugLabel}
) compute` - so it is `Q message,` - the second parameter

Comment: I'm using compute like this ```await compute(saveImages, [parameter list]);``` should i add receivePort to list?

Comment: Thank you so much!! It works as I expected!!

Comment: good, your welcome, post a self answer then so it would be useful to others

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink), I find out solution.
First, create RecceivePort and pass receivePort.sendPort to compute method.

```
ReceivePort receivePort;

myComputeFunction(args) {
    Int someParameter = args[0]
    String otherParameter = args[1]
    SendPort port = args[2]

    //if you want to send some message
    port.send("your message here(passing double was ok)")
}


callingComputeFunction() {
    await compute(myComputeFunction, [1, "string", receivePort.sendPort]);
}
```

And before you call `compute`, don't forget to `receivePort.listen()`.

```
receivePort.listen((dynamic message) {
      //do whatever you want to do with message!
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
progressDialog.update(progress: 50.0)   add Double Value Here it will work
```

Your progress value is not double so you are getting this error

Comment: I just used ```(progress: progress)``` for instant expression. the value i pass to progress variable is double.

Comment: add a static double value and check . then you can understand the problem is in the progressDialog.update(progress: progress) instant expression. you need to change the instant expression